# Populate "Lookup Table" with random values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables, `A` `B` and `C`. For every entry in `A x B` (where x is a Cartesian product, or cross join) there is an entry in `C`.

In other words, the table for `C` might look like this, if there were 2 entries for `A` and 3 for `B`:

```
| A_ID | B_ID | C_Val |
----------------------|
|  1   |  1   |  100  |
|  1   |  2   |  56   |
|  1   |  3   |  19   |
|  2   |  1   |  67   |   
|  2   |  2   |  0    |
|  2   |  3   |  99   |
```

Thus, for any combination of `A` and `B`, there's a value to be looked up in `C`. I hope this all makes sense.

In practice, the size of `A x B` may be relatively small for a database, but far too large to populate by hand for testing data.  Thus, I would like to randomlly populate `C`'s table for whatever data may already be in `A` and `B`.

My knowledge of SQL is fairly basic. What I've determined I can do so far is get that cartesian product as an inner query, like so:

```
(SELECT B.B_ID, C.C_ID
 FROM B CROSS JOIN C)
```

Then I want to say something like follows:

```
INSERT INTO A(B_ID, C_ID, A_Val) VALUES
    (SELECT B.B_ID, C.C_ID, FLOOR(RAND() * 100)
     FROM B CROSS JOIN C)
```

Not surprisingly, this doesn't work. I don't think its valid syntax to genereate a column on the fly like that, nor to try to insert a whole table as values.

How can I basically convert this normal programming pseudocode to proper SQL?

```
foreach(A_ID in A){
    foreach(B_ID in B){
        C.insert(A_ID, B_ID, Rand(100));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax problem is because:

```
INSERT INTO A(B_ID, C_ID, A_Val) VALUES
  (SELECT B.B_ID, C.C_ID, FLOOR(RAND() * 100)
   FROM B CROSS JOIN C)
```

Should be:

```
INSERT INTO A(B_ID, C_ID, A_Val) 
  SELECT B.B_ID, C.C_ID, FLOOR(RAND() * 100)
   FROM B CROSS JOIN C;
```

(You don't use `VALUES` with `INSERT/SELECT`.)

However you will still have the problem that `RAND()` is not evaluated for every row; it will have the same value for every row. Assuming the combination of B_ID and C_ID is unique, you can use something like this:

```
INSERT INTO A(B_ID, C_ID, A_Val) 
  SELECT B.B_ID, C.C_ID, ABS(CHEKSUM(RAND(B.B_ID*C.C_ID))) % 100
   FROM B CROSS JOIN C;
```

Comment: It will take some time..I guess to get used  maybe untill we get a score of 45.8 K like Aaron :).I am still not used to comments.I always forget and press enter and my comment get posted.With comment worst thing is that it can be edited just for five minutes...

Comment: Working answer and great explanation too. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
select A_id,B_Id, abs(checksum(newid()))%101 as C_val from A cross join B
```

This will give you different values in ranmge 0 to 100

Answer (score 0):

Use CTE

```
  With cte as
  (SELECT B.B_ID, C.C_ID, ABS(CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY) AS INT)) as A_Val
    FROM B CROSS JOIN C) 
  Insert into Table(B_ID, C_ID, A_Val)
  Select B_ID,C_ID,A_Val from cte
```

Since rand generates the same number you can use NEWID .[Source](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/generate-random-numbers.aspx)

Comment: This is a whole lot of extra scaffolding for a simple INSERT/SELECT. And doesn't solve the RAND() issue.

Comment: Then possibly he can use NEWID which will return different value for each row

Comment: Maybe, but your solution doesn't really solve either problem IMHO. All you've done is make the syntax needlessly complex.

Comment: CTE and apply are two features which are sometimes used unnecessarily..I guess it now becomes habit to use these..